# Define custom method and access it from twig

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I have two entities in 1:n relations: Race and Day - a race may have more days. This is the simple model:

```
Race (id)

Day (id, race_id, is_active, is_deleted)
```

I want to access the superior one - Race - within a Symfony2 project via Doctrine and display results in a Twig template. For the direct Race attributes it is easy.

However, it becomes trickier, when I want to use a custom defined method (sort of flag, let's call it hasActiveDays()) in Race that reflects if the race had any active and not deleted days. Simple Doctrine relation would not be enough, so I need to use a query like this:

```
SELECT d FROM mtboLibBundle:Day d WHERE d.isActive = 1 AND d.isDeleted = 0 AND d.raceId = :id
```

My question is basicly **where/how to implement this query and how to invoke it in a twig template?** Anything I tried resulted various errors so far, so I'd be grateful if someone could help.

I.e. this was a try:

```
class RaceRepository extends EntityRepository {
    public function hasActiveDays() {
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT f FROM mtboLibBundle:Day d
            WHERE d.isActive = 1
            AND d.isDeleted = 0
            AND d.raceId = :id')
                ->setParameter('id', $this->id)
                ;
        $days = $query->getResult();
        return (count($days) == 0) ? false : true;
    }
}
```

Method does not exist - when called from the template:

```
{{ race.hasActiveDays }}
```

Comment: Start with the [Custom Repository Classes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) and send the result to the view.

Comment: I've tried that, this resulted a "Method does not exist" error.

Comment: Ok not sure you need the customer repository, can you show us your full twig template?

Comment: It's a lot of irrelevant HTML only. This call is the key: {{ race.hasActiveDays }}

Comment: What I wanted to know is if this call is part of a `for` loop. In your particular case, I don't think you even need to create a function `hasActiveDays`. You can probably rely on the properties of the object you are using in your view.

Comment: Yes, it is in a loop. But it is more complex then using a simple property. Meanwhile, I got the solution, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to call a function in a repository the way you are trying to do. One thing I've done is put a function on the entity class and you can call that from your template.

In your Race class:

```
public function hasActiveDays(){
    // here, perhaps pull all of the days for this race - maybe from a doctrine relation
    // loop through, filter, etc.
    // return whatever is appropriate
}
```

... then, in your template, you'll be able to call that function the way you are trying to above.

Comment: This I've tried as well. The problem was how to make the query from within az entity class. Calls like $this->getEntityManager() or $this->getDoctrine() won't work here, since $this refers to the entity itself.

Comment: Based on the way I did something similar, in Race you have a Days property with a '@ORM\OneToMany' relationship to your Days entity, in your constructor a '$this->days = new ArrayCollection()', and a method 'getDays()' that returns that collection, then you could have the method on the Race entity called 'hasActiveDays()' that loops through '$this->getDays()' looking for days that are active (I assume this is a property on Day) and returning that list. More on Doctrine relationships FYI: [link](http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations)

Comment: Great!!! Would you mind marking my answer as accepted? I'm new here and trying to build up some rep. Thanks! :-)

Comment: I did. But. :) It's great for a flag method, but what if I want to list those active, not deleted days? Is there any better approach then looping through $this->getDays() and build an array of objects? Is it maybe possible to make a query inside an entity?

Comment: Thanks! But. :-) Perhaps I'm not understanding your data model well enough. If "active" is a property on days, inside the hasActiveDays() function, first create an ArrayCollection (`$activeDays = new ArrayCollection()`), then loop through the race's days ( `foreach($this->getDays() as $day){ if ($day->active == true) { $activeDays->add($day); } }`. It may be possible to make a query inside an entity, but it wouldn't be best practice to do so. If I'm not understanding what you are looking for, then maybe clarify some more and we'll see where we are.

Comment: Actually ... `if($day->getActive() == true) ...`

Comment: On a related note ... there is a great Symfony2 tutorial I've been working back through at: http://www.ens.ro/tag/symfony2-jobeet/ ... It's cool to go through this after I've worked with Symfony some to see what I've missed and/or could be doing better.

Comment: Thanks for jobeet, I did not know it existed for Symfony2.